# Tensorflow - Restoring model fail with message " Attempting to use uninitialized value"

Tags: model, tensorflow, restore, checkpoint

I am really new to the TensorFlow so bear with me plz even if this question is a total nonsense...

I have a code which

1) defines the network like

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 784], name='input')
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 10], name='reference')
...
fc_b2_hist = tf.summary.histogram('b_fc2', b_fc2)
```

2) then restoring the model with

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
  #NOTE
  #sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
  model_path = tf.train.latest_checkpoint(model_path)
  saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(model_path+'.meta')
  saver.restore(sess, model_path)

  all_vars = tf.trainable_variables()
    for v in all_vars:
    print(sess.run(v))
```

this code, which restores the model, works perfectly fine when run in the separate file.
however, when run on this, it aborts with the following error message

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "lenet_my.py", line 160, in
>   
>       print(sess.run(v))   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py",
>   line 766, in run
>       run_metadata_ptr)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py",
>   line 964, in _run
>       feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py",
>   line 1014, in _do_run
>       target_list, options, run_metadata)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py",
>   line 1034, in _do_call
>       raise type(e)(node_def, op, message) tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError:
>   Attempting to use uninitialized value lenet_model/conv_pool_1/W_conv1
>            [[Node: _send_lenet_model/conv_pool_1/W_conv1_0 = _SendT=DT_FLOAT, client_terminated=true, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0",
>   send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0",
>   send_device_incarnation=422131278131772803,
>   tensor_name="lenet_model/conv_pool_1/W_conv1:0",
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]]

after I saw this message for the first time, I uncommented the line under #NOTE, which is

```
sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
```

it did not show such error, but the pretrained variables were not restored and was initialized by how I defined it while defining the network.

So I have two questions!

First, I don't get what the difference is between running the code in a separate file and running it in one file to get such HORRIFYING error message
Second, I don't get why initializing the variables then restoring the model with the code written above does not restore the previously trained variables.

Thnx in advance

Comment: Were you able to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I think what might  help is ***not*** running `tf.train.import_meta_graph()`.
The import from `.meta` file will create a new graph as specified in the file, which you do not need as you just built your own graph.

Just say:

```
saver = tf.train.Saver()
with tf.Session() as sess:
  model_path = tf.train.latest_checkpoint(model_path)
  saver.restore(sess, model_path)
```

Comment: See this link for a nice overview/explanation with some more context: https://www.easy-tensorflow.com/tf-tutorials/convolutional-neural-nets-cnns/cnn1?view=category&id=86.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you should put

```
saver=tf.train.import_meta_graph(model_path+'.meta')
```

out of your ‘Session’

Here is a sclie of my code:

```
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('./models/xxx.ckpt-30000.meta')
with tf.Session() as sess:
    saver.restore(sess,'./models/xxx.ckpt-30000')
```

Hope it is useful